# Match special characters including square braces

Tags: javascript, regex, extjs

I want to have a regex for text field in ExtJs(maskRe) which matches all java code pattern

I've used

```
    maskRe:/^[A-Za-z0-9 _=//~'"|{}();*:?+,.]*$/
```

I also want to include [,], but it seems /[, /], //[, //] is not working..

Any inputs please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you need to escape your forward slash. Change `//` to `\/`:

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9 _=\/~'"|{}();*:?+,.]*$/
```

However this regular expression does *not* match any Java code. Java code can contain almost any Unicode character. `int møøse = 42;` is valid Java.

Answer (score 1):

To strip special characters from its magic powers you have to `escape` them, by putting  backslash `\` in front of character. I.e. to match `[` you type `\[`.

And since backslash acts as special character as well, to match it literally, you escape it the same way: `\\`.

And since you used `/` as patter delimiter, you need to escape its occurrences within pattern:

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9 _=\/~'"|{}();*:?+,.]*$/
```

Answer (score 1):

The way to escape **[regex meta-characters](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html)** is using a backslash `(\)`, not a forwards slash `(/)`.

`[,]` should be `\[,\]`

`//` should be `\/`